# I'm trying to apply position sticky, but it's not working on the Iphone only

Tags: javascript, css, angular, iphone

I have a problem using positio sticky in Iphone. It's working perfectly on android, windows. But on the Iphone it doesn't work. It is simply fixed to the bootom of the page,
Below is the code and the structure of the code

```css
.button-sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: -moz-sticky;
  position: -o-sticky;
  position: -ms-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10px;
  min-width: 40%;
  z-index: 100;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  &::before {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper>
  </div>
   <ion-button
    class="ion-margin-top vaga-interna-botao-sticky"
    size="large"
  >
    <ng-container >
      <i class="fas fa-check"></i>
      <span>I want to sign up</span>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-button>
</div>
```

Comment: "But on the Iphone it doesn't work". How doesnt it work? Please describe that better. Maybe you can add a screenshot of how it looks on an actual iphone?

Comment: On other devices it stays fixed on the bottom until it reaches the footer.  On iPhone it is fixed at the bottom of the page

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Kb8.jpg "IPHONE"
   /        https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm8YZ.jpg